# How to carry out this change of variable?

Tags: partial-derivative, change-of-variable

I think this is a fairly basic question but I am just unable to crack it.

Given that $ u= f(x) + g(y)$, how do I write $\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial u^2}$ in terms of $ \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial y^2}$ for some $\psi(u)?$?

I think this involves the chain rule but I'm not sure how to apply it for partial derivatives. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is quite a lenghty computation: use $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$
and then derive again, using again the chain rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

If $u(x,y)=f(x)+g(y)$ and $x,y$ are independent variable than
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=f'(x) \qquad\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=g'(y)
$$
and

$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f'(x)=f''(x) \qquad\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g'(y)=g''(y)
$$

Now use the chain rule to find the derivatives of $\psi(u)$

Comment: Is this the answer?:        $\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial u^2} = \frac{\partial u }{\partial x} \left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \frac{\partial }{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2} \right) + \frac{\partial u }{\partial y} \left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} \frac{\partial }{\partial y} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y^2} \right)$

Comment: which simplifies to: $ \frac{\partial^2} {\partial u^2}= f'(x) \left(f''(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + f'(x) \frac{\partial^2} {\partial x^2} \right) + g'(y) \left(g''(y) \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + g'(y) \frac{\partial^2}
 {\partial y^2} \right)$